# adding image inside a circle progress indicator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this cool progress ring from  Matěj Husák and I want to add an image inside the ring like this:

[image]

Here is the original code:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.ring-circle');
const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
const circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

function setProgressFromButton() {
    setProgress(document.getElementById("input-percent").value);
}

setProgress(10);
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2D132C;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Sanchez, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
}

button:active {
    outline: none;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.container {
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.button-start {
    font-family: Sanchez;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 6px 26px;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C72C41;;
    background: #EE4540;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: 250ms ease;
}

.button-start:hover {
    background: #EE342F;

}

.button-start:active {
    border-bottom: none;
}


h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ring {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.ring-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 10 20;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.60s ease;
}

#input-percent {
    width: 121px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #881238;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #660B28;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Sanchez;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: right;
}

.input-wrapper {
    width: max-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

input:active {
    outline: none;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>The progress ring</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 id="main-header">The progress ring.</h1>
      
      
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3"/>

    <svg class="ring" height="200" width="200">
        <circle stroke-width="18" stroke="#801336" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/>
        <circle class="ring-circle" stroke-width="18" stroke="#EE4540" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
    </svg>

    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="input-percent" value="10" type="text" name="" id="">
        <button onclick="setProgressFromButton()" id="confirm-button" class="button-start">Ok</button>
    </div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is he used SVG as the ring and I'm unable to find a **Proper Solution** to put the image inside the circle without ruining other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<foreignObject ...>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to embed html inside an svg. Then it's just a matter of styling the image to suit your needs.

eg.

```
<foreignObject height="150" width="150" x="25" y="25">
  <img
    src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3"
    style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  />
</foreignObject>
```

Here's a rough edit of what you've got:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.ring-circle');
const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
const circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

function setProgressFromButton() {
    setProgress(document.getElementById("input-percent").value);
}

setProgress(10);
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2D132C;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Sanchez, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
}

button:active {
    outline: none;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.container {
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.button-start {
    font-family: Sanchez;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 6px 26px;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C72C41;;
    background: #EE4540;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: 250ms ease;
}

.button-start:hover {
    background: #EE342F;

}

.button-start:active {
    border-bottom: none;
}


h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ring {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.ring-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 10 20;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.60s ease;
}

#input-percent {
    width: 121px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #881238;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #660B28;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Sanchez;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: right;
}

.input-wrapper {
    width: max-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

input:active {
    outline: none;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>The progress ring</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sanchez&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 id="main-header">The progress ring.</h1>
      
      
    <svg class="ring" height="200" width="200">
        <circle stroke-width="18" stroke="#801336" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/>
        <circle class="ring-circle" stroke-width="18" stroke="#EE4540" fill="transparent" r="84" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
        
        <foreignObject height="150" width="150" x="25" y="25">
          <img
    src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18320/profile/profile-512.jpg?3"
    style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  />
      </foreignObject>

    </svg>

    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input id="input-percent" value="10" type="text" name="" id="">
        <button onclick="setProgressFromButton()" id="confirm-button" class="button-start">Ok</button>
    </div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image is rotated in this demo because of your

```
.ring {
  ...
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Easy enough to fix that.